# Using CNAME to point to other website does not work

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, web-hosting, cname-record, host

I have below domain name registered on Hostinger
`himanshupoddar.tech`

I added CNAME record to point my domain to another website "okcredit.com"

[image]

But it does not work and I am still not being redirected to the okcredit website when I visit himanshupoddar.tech.

Someone said to wait for 5mins for the same to show up but its been an hour now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment, but its too big to fit in the box provided.

Please take some time to learn how DNS works.

> I added CNAME record

It would have been helpful if you had said where the NS records point to and where you made this change (should have been on the Google nameservers where the domain is hosted). Your use of verbs and nouns in the following sentence makes no sense. And you can't use a CNAME for "okcredit.com" (you can for "www.okcredit.com")

> Someone said to wait for 5mins

The TTL on your CNAME records says to wait 4 hours - but the zone TTL might be even longer. Currently (22:16 UTC) the Google nameservers are still returning the A record 35.241.2.172

Go back and check in four hours. If it's still not returning your CNAME, go check what you input on Google and while you are there reduce the TTL (it will take until the old TTL expires before the new TTL comes into effect).

> am still not being redirected to the okcredit website when I visit himanshupoddar.tech

Perhaps english is not your first language. DNS does not "redirect" and the changes you have made will associate [www.okcredit.com](http://www.okcredit.com) with the same IP as himanshupoddar.tech not vice versa.

Comment: I may have misunderstood everything, but I was hoping if my domain `himanshupoddar.tech` can point to `okcredit.com`. So that when someone visits my my domain he is directly taken to okcredit. Is that possible?

Comment: If you want someone to be REDIRECTED from himanshupoddar.tech to okcredit.com then you should implement an HTTP redirect on the himanshupoddar.tech webserver.

Comment: So in that case why do i even need CNAME if all it does is internal domain translation

Comment: You don't. Actually what you do by adding the CNAME record above is to map the name  www.himanshupoddar.tech to the host holding the content for www.okcredit.com but the http server there won't respond to that traffic without giving errors and you will also have issues with HTTPS certificates.